# git push with double dash (git push --)

Tags: git

I am familiar with the use of `--` in commands such as `git checkout --` when you want to separate the branch from the file `git checkout -- master`. However I have never seen `git push --` and can't find anything in the man page or https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push about it.

The command I ran into was

```
git push -- origin e96b75aec4014a898cebfb0619599d8171f62c66:master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a no-op.

`git-push` doesn't take any file arguments like `git-checkout` does so there is no need for the [*bare double-dash*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash) and it is ignored.

A note-worthy, but unrelated aspect of the push command you have listed is that it is using [the refspec syntax](http://blog.endpoint.com/2008/07/git-push-know-your-refspecs.html) but that is not related to the `--`.

You can similarly use it with `git-branch` even though it also does not take any file arguments (ex: `git branch -- fooBranch` is equivalent to `git branch fooBranch`)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a git-specific option (at least not for push), therefore it's not explained in the docs.

What it is actually used for:

> a double dash (--) is used in bash built-in commands and many other commands to signify the end of command options, after which only positional parameters are accepted.

More details at [unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash).

Comment: @xaa what a "coincidence", that is exactly the page I linked to and quoted from..